# Find $a,b,c,d$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : (x^2+cx+d)^{10}=(2x-1)^{20}-(ax+b)^{20}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

One of my colleagues show me the below question and asked me to solve it.
find $a,b,c,d$ as real numbers such that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : (x^2+cx+d)^{10}=(2x-1)^{20}-(ax+b)^{20}$$ so I started to put some $x$ into equation,for example $x=0 \to d^{10}=1-b^{20}$ or $x=1 \to (1+c+d)^{10}=1-(a+b)^{20} $and so on...
but honestly, I got no clue to find $a,b,c,d$ in an ordinary way.
another trial was to show for the l.h.s and R.h.s coefficient, but it's complicated to solve $$\underbrace{(x^2)^{10}}_{1x^{20}}+\cdots=\underbrace{(2x)^{20}-(ax)^{20}}_{1x^{20}}+\cdots$$

can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does this have the calculus tag?  It's not obvious how it relates to calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that for $x \neq \frac12$

$$(x^2+cx+d)^{10}=(2x-1)^{20}-(ax+b)^{20} \\\iff \frac1{4^{10}}\left(\frac{x^2+cx+d}{x^2-x+\frac14}\right)^{10}=1-\left(\frac{ax+b}{2x-1}\right)^{20}$$

from which we find $c=-1$, $d=\frac14$ and $a=- 2b$ such that

$$\frac1{4^{10}}=1-b^{20} \implies b=\pm\left(1-\frac1{4^{10}}\right)^\frac1{20}$$

Comment: Very nice 1-shot approach +1

Comment: Thanks! Your approach also is very fine. Bye

Comment: High precision calculation of $b$: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLstUw1DWJ0zU00IzTMNQ3MtDk5Sooyswr0UjSy9NIyUzPLCm2NTQw0NQEAOEICxY=&lang=sage

Answer (score 3):

You may find this slightly quicker:

$x = \frac12 \implies \quad (\frac14+\frac12c+d)^{10}+(\frac12a+b)^{20}=0 \\ \implies d = -\frac14-\frac12c,\; b=-\frac12a$

Now $x=0 \implies d^{10}=1-b^{20} = 1-\left(\frac{a}2\right)^{20}$ and

$x = 1 \implies (1+c+d)^{10}=1-(a+b)^{20}= 1-\left(\frac{a}2\right)^{20}=d^{10} \\ \implies 1+c \in\{0, -2d\}$.

It is not hard to finish now, to get $(c, d) = ( -1, \frac14)$ and $a = \pm 2 \cdot\sqrt[20]{1-\frac1{4^{10}}} \approx \pm 1.99999990, b = \mp \sqrt[20]{1-\frac1{4^{10}}} \approx \mp 0.99999995$.